# How many different way exists to define 2D array with pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I try to define a 2D array with C++ with pointers and I don't know how can I define it true? I have some loops in the function and they are start with 1 to n and I want to allocate memory and at the end of function I want to delete allocated memory?
for define it like the following code. please help me to develop it.

```
int **W;
W = new int* [n];
for (int i=1; i <= n; i++)
   W[i] = new int[n];
///////////////////////
for (int k=1;k<=n;k++)
   for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
      for (int j=1;j<=n;j++)
         do some thing!
///////////////////////
for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )
    delete [] W[i];
delete W;
```

Comment: What are you asking? Did you see it crash?

Answer (score 0):

For an array of size n, indices start from 0 - (n-1). Thus array[n] is out of bounds.

```
    int **W;
    int n = 3;
    W = new int*[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        W[i] = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        delete[] W[i];
    delete W;
```

Comment: I try your answer but Microsoft visual studio break by this error: **Unhandled exception at 0x59fc4f98 (msvcr110.dll) in file.exe: 0xc000005 Access violation reading location 0xfeeefeee2.**

Comment: i wrote that code with Visual Studio. I dont get any error.

Comment: check your code again. You might have changed a thing or two. Else, try to clean project and rebuild solution.  Works also with gcc. https://ideone.com/nI7QeN

Answer (score 0):

You have the general idea correct. But there are some errors in the details. C/C++ use `0`-based indices to access arrays.

```
for (int i=1; i <= n; i++)
   W[i] = new int[n];
```

needs to be

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
   W[i] = new int[n];
```

Similar changes need to be made in the other `for` statements.

Also, you need to delete `W` using the array delete operator. Instead of

```
delete W;
```

use

```
delete [] W;
```

Having said that, you should use `std::vector` instead of plain old dynamic arrays. With `std::vector`, you don't have to worry about deallocation of memory. The destructor of `std::vector` will take care of deallocating memory.

A 2D array of size `n` x `n` where each element is initialized to `0` can be defined simply as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(n, std::vector<int>(n, 0));
```

Comment: What about the `delete W;` at the end deleting an array?